# How to pass Thunderforest API key to the R ggspatial package to create a map

Tags: r, openstreetmap, rosm, ggspatial, thunderforest

I am creating maps using the `rosm` and `ggspatial` R package. The `ggosm` function is easy to use to extract a base map layer based on the spatial object provided. Here is an example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(rosm)
library(ggspatial)

ggosm() + 
  geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
```

[image]

This works great. I can change the base map layer to other types (See `osm.types()` for available types. Here is an example to use `cartolight` as the base map layer.

```
ggosm(type = "cartolight") + 
  geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
```

[image]

This also works. Now my question is **how to pass Thunderforest API key**? If I used the type as `thunderforestoutdoors`, I got the following output.

```
ggosm(type = "thunderforestoutdoors") + 
  geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
```

[image]

Clearly, I need the Thunderforest API key, so I have registered an API key from https://www.thunderforest.com/. This page (https://www.thunderforest.com/docs/apikeys/) shows how to use the API key. The documentation of `rosm` also shows that users can define map tiles by providing the URL (See `?as.tile_source`). Nevertheless, it seems like the general structure of URL is like: `https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=<insert-your-apikey-here>`. I will need to know the `z`, `x`, and `y` (zoom level and tile number) to specify the tile. It is not possible because I have a lot of spatial objects to plot and I need `ggosm` to determine the right zoom level and tiles for me. It would be great if anyone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution:

*Chuckle - There is a way to do this do this with rosm* **without** *modifying the library*.

- Use the `rosm:: source_from_url_format()` function. This is what it was designed to do, it is documented in the rosm package. [Admittedly somewhat briefly]

Note - I cover how to hide your public API key when using shared code under a separate follow-on bullet for completeness.

I hope this helps, it should at the very least make it easier for those who want to do what you propose without requiring library modifications.

Take Care
T.

### Example Usage: source_from_url_format()

**Note**: Replace `<insert key>` with your private key from the Thunderforest website.

```
if (!require(ggplot2)) install.packages("ggplot2")
if (!require(rosm)) install.packages("rosm")
if (!require(ggspatial)) install.packages("ggspatial")
if (!require(sp)) install.packages("sp")

thunderforest = source_from_url_format(
  url_format = c('http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=<insert key>',
                 'http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=<insert key>',
                 'http://c.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=<insert key>'),
  attribution = "More on Thunderforest at http://www.thunderforest.com/"
)

ggosm(type = thunderforest) + 
  geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
```

### Example Runtime output:

```
> if (!require(ggplot2)) install.packages("ggplot2")
> if (!require(rosm)) install.packages("rosm")
> if (!require(ggspatial)) install.packages("ggspatial")
> if (!require(sp)) install.packages("sp")
> thunderforest = source_from_url_format(

+   url_format = c('http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=<secret>',
+                  'http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=<secret>',
+                  'http://c.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=<secret>'),
+   attribution = "More on Thunderforest at http://www.thunderforest.com/"
+ )
> ggosm(type = thunderforest) + 
+   geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
Converting coordinates to lat/lon (epsg:4326)
Zoom: 15
Fetching 4 missing tiles
  |===================================================================================================================================| 100%
...complete!
```

### Output Plot:

[image]

### Hide your Thunderforest API Key from public Code

A separate but related problem is how you should hide your API key from your public code. The recommended approach is to add your API key to your `~/.Renviron` file.

```
THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY="<insert api key"`
```

we retrieve the environment variable via a call too:

```
Sys.getenv("THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY")
```

now we can invoke this from within an R program as follows:

```
if (!require(ggplot2)) install.packages("ggplot2")
if (!require(rosm)) install.packages("rosm")
if (!require(ggspatial)) install.packages("ggspatial")
if (!require(sp)) install.packages("sp")

thunderforest = source_from_url_format(
  url_format = c(paste0('http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=',Sys.getenv("THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY")),
                 paste0('http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=',Sys.getenv("THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY")),
                 paste0('http://c.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=',Sys.getenv("THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY"))),
  attribution = "More on Thunderforest at http://www.thunderforest.com/"
)

ggosm(type = thunderforest) +
  geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
```

### Executed Code

Using this example it is much easier to share your code. **No keys need to be included in the published code** ;-)

```
> if (!require(ggplot2)) install.packages("ggplot2")
> if (!require(rosm)) install.packages("rosm")
> if (!require(ggspatial)) install.packages("ggspatial")
> if (!require(sp)) install.packages("sp")    
> thunderforest = source_from_url_format(

+   url_format = c(paste0('http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=',Sys.getenv("THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY")),
+                  paste0('http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=',Sys.getenv("THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY")),
+                  paste0('http://c.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png?apikey=',Sys.getenv("THUNDERFOREST_API_KEY"))),
+   attribution = "More on Thunderforest at http://www.thunderforest.com/"
+ )
> ggosm(type = thunderforest) +
+   geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
Converting coordinates to lat/lon (epsg:4326)
Zoom: 15
```

### Output Plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works well. I think your post will also be helpful for others who want to insert API key.

Comment: @ycw Great - thankyou. Key distribution through .Renviron is (in my view) much less of headache. I learnt through much pain and suffering - chuckle. Always happy to help, have great day.

Comment: @Technophobe01 not sure what changed but this approach no longer works, when you try to use rosm::source_from_url_format it doesn't seem to like the api key added to the end of the url, throws up an error in match.arg, 'arg' should be one of "png'

Comment: Let me take a look… currently traveling back from holidays on September 28th.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's currently a way to do this with ggspatial or rosm at the moment. [So, I forked rosm](https://github.com/jonathande4/rosm) and modified one of the functions to include an api key if it's found in your environment.

#### Short Term Solution

You can just use the forked repo.

```
# Packages
devtools::install_github("jonathande4/rosm")
library(rosm)
library(ggspatial)

# Set environment.
Sys.setenv("THUNDERFOREST_KEY" = "YOUR_API_KEY")

# Plot
ggosm(type = "thunderforestoutdoors") + 
  geom_spatial(longlake_waterdf, fill = NA, color = "black")
```

Which outputs this map, free from watermarks.

[image: output]

#### Long Term Solution

I'd like to try and submit a pull request for this change. If there are any changes in implementation that deviate from the original solution, I'll post an update.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for working on this. I tried your solution but there are still water marks. Perhaps I inserted my API key incorrectly. Does `"YOUR_API_KEY"` a series of numbers and letters?

Comment: Can you try and make sure your map cache is clear? If not, it won't fetch new tiles.

Comment: I started a new R session and ran your code. It is still the same. Does starting a new R session clear the map cache?

Comment: Check your project or working directory. There's a folder there that you can remove. Or, a "cachedir" option in the ggosm function which you should set to FALSE. Restarting R isn't enough.

Comment: Add `forcedownload = TRUE` to the `ggosm` call to force downloading new tiles works. It is great! Thank you so much and I do think you can submit a pull request for this change.

Comment: @jonathande4 - You don't need to modify the rosm package to do this. See example - use `rosm::source_from_url_format()`.

Comment: @jonathande4 Separately, if you want to pass environment variables into an R program the recommended approach is to use `.Renviron`. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084284/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-shinyapps/39680458#39680458

Comment: @ycw You don't need to modify the rosm package to do this. See example - use rosm::source_from_url_format() - just making sure you are aware.

Comment: @jonathande4 Technophobe01's solution works well. Since `source_from_url_format` is already in the `rosm` package, I decided to accept Technophobe01's answer. But thank you for working on this and sharing your solution.

Comment: That's fine! It's a cleaner solution and saves me from writing a pull request.