# shinyapps.io won't read environment variables from .Renviron

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny, shinyapps, r-environment

I have created a package containing a `run_app` function (which calls a Shiny app with `runApp`) and uploaded it to a private GitHub repository.

The package folder is like this:

```
project_name/
       project_name.Rproj
       DESCRIPTION
       NAMESPACE
       .Renviron (hidden)
       (other git hidden files)
       R/
           app.R
```

Within the app, I use methods such as `get_bucket`, hence I need AWS credentials to be read by the app. Locally, it works beautifully, since Rstudio is able to retrieve variables from .Renviron without any problems.

When I deploy the app, though, `Sys.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")` for example returns a string with 0 length, rather than the variable I wrote in .Renviron.

The app *is* deployed normally, but the AWS methods that need environment variables won't work, since the script is failing to read the .Renviron file.

The app is deployed like this:

1. I have another folder containing another `app.R` file such as

```
library(repository_name)

repository_name::run_app()
```

2. Then I execute

```
tmp.enc <- options()$encoding
options(encoding = "UTF-8", rsconnect.packrat = TRUE)

rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = path/to/the/folder/containing/the/.R/file,
                     appName = "app_adress",
                     upload = TRUE, logLevel = "verbose", lint = TRUE, forceUpdate = TRUE)
```

I've tried many things, such as:

1. Making sure the last line in .Renviron is empty
2. Deploying from the project's working directory
3. Trying to run `readRenviron(".Renviron")` at the start of the app's server function
4. Trying to run `readRenviron("~/.Renviron")` at the start of the app's server function
5. Trying to run `readRenviron(normalizePath('.Renviron'))` at the start of the app's server
   function
6. Always making sure the .Renviron existed in the working directory I was deploying from

I really don't want to store the .Renviron in the repository, since it's not safe. I believe there must be a way for the shinyapps.io to understand my environment when deploying.

It's also not optimal to execute `Sys.setenv` with my credentials everytime I needed to deploy an app. Ideally, the deploy should understand my .Renviron, but I'm probably doing something wrong that prevents it.

This unfortunately didn't help: [How to pass environment variables to shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084284/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-shinyapps)

Comment: I would start by downloading that deployed bundle from shinyapps.io (if this is where your are hosting) to check if it actually contains `.Renviron`. Maybe I'm missing something, but from `appDir = path/to/the/folder/containing/the/.R/file` I'd assume it's not included.

Comment: Thank you! I am the one who was missing something! The .Renviron needs indeed to be in the folder `path/to/the/folder/containing/the/.R/file` (the one with the reproduced app). I knew I was missing something trivial. I was trying to put the .Renviron in the same folder as the project (the working directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As margusl pointed out, the .Renviron needs to be in the folder path/to/the/folder/containing/the/.R/file (the one with the reproduced app), not in the folder where the project is (working directory).